# Force CMake to look for x64 bit libraries instead of x32

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

So I've been looking around in stackoverflow and some other forums how to force CMake to look for the x64 libraries instead of x32 and it didn't really help much.

When I do:

```
find_package(Boost
    1.67.0
    COMPONENTS
        atomic
    REQUIRED
)
```

for some reason CMake looks for the x32 libraries instead of the x64 ones and fails to find them. I know this by adding this option in the cmake command:

```
-DBoost_DEBUG=ON
```

Which shows me this(It shows of course more than what I posted, but I posted the important lines):

```
_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/develop/libraries/boost/1.67.0/x64-vc141/Release/lib
Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc141-mt;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc140-mt;boost_atomic-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
```

But instead of looking for this:

```
boost_atomic-vc141-mt-x32-1_67
```

Which is obvious why it can't find it.
I want it to look for this:

```
boost_atomic-vc141-mt-x64-1_67
```

What am I missing? is there some extra CMake configuration I suppose to add in order to make CMake understand that I'm using boost for x64 architecture?

I even tried to start `Developer Command Prompt for VS 17` in x64 mode the manual way by calling:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are you generating? Visual Studio solution?

Comment: It's a library project, not trying to generate VS solution, just make files so I can build it after with cmake --build command. Here is my generate command: `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\tmpppp -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate anything with CMake you should specify a generator unless the default one suites your needs. Looks like in your case the default one (whatever it is) doesn't work for you so you should provide it like this (for MSVS 2015):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```

Note the architecture in the generator it is important for the search. Later you can build it with the CMake --build but you still have to generate some *make* files which are using x64 compiler.

Comment: Oh wow...Strangely though it actually worked! I was thinking CMake should have some option for that, to define architecture type explicitly, but I guess everything happens behind the scene and this is great work around solution! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @GiladReich, it is likely that you do not fully understand what CMake is and what it is not. It is a simple (well, not that simple) generator tool which goal is to have some common make file language which allows generating other make files out of it. For example, you write one CMake file and then generate Visual Studio, XCode, Borland etc. projects out of it. CMake --build is a relatively new thing in CMake which just uses some external tool to build the project (in case of MSVS it is MSBuild). It doesn't know how to build anything it just delegates.

Comment: thanks for the headsup! appreciate that. But I already know these stuff. Just that the project I'm working on, use some of the advance features of CMake, as you say "not that simple" that I'm slowly getting to know. I knew about the VS solution generator, till now I just used the NMake JOM generator, but I never knew it has the Win64 option, it's a new thing for the project I'm working on to build the library in x64 which is why I didn't overlooked at it. Thanks to you I found out about it.

Comment: Speaking of which, do you have any idea by any chance if it's possible to do the same thing(x64 architecture) using the JOM generator? Because with JOM I could specify how many cores to use to build the project.

Comment: @GiladReich, running cmake from the console where x64 env has been established and picking the correct generator "NMake Makefiles JOM" should do what you need. Just opened vanilla cmd, run there `vcvars64.bat`, then run `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"` and it picked the correct x64 compiler which should be enough to detect the correct boost version.

Comment: did you call the vcvars64.bat in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat` ? I tried it now and it seems to still not pick up the correct x64 boost libraries. Here is my simple command: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "NMake Makefiles JOM" ..`

Comment: Just in case anyone else looking into this, there is a way of doing the same with msvc compiler by passing the compiler parameters defining the cores to use during compilation, i.e: `cmake --build . --config Release --clean-first -- /m:8 /p:BuildInParallel=true`

Comment: @GiladReich, I run vanilla cmd: Win+R->cmd->Enter, then `cd` to the folder where  vcvars64.bat is, then `cd` where my sources is, then run cmake and everything were picked up correctly. I don't quite remember the exact path I used for the batch file but it looks like it was something like `Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`, and it was the 2017 studio.