# Cmake boost looking for wrong architecture type

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to run [OpenNERO](https://github.com/nnrg/opennero) on my Windows 10. I had installed all the dependencies mentioned on their wiki for building it. My Python version is 2.7.15 and boost version is 1.67

Below are the content of my "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib" folder:
[image]

When I tried running cmake I found that it is trying to look for files in the format "boost_python27-vc141-mt-x32-1_67" while in my boost directory shown above, they are present in the format "boost_python27-vc141-mt-x64-1_67", only difference being the x32/64 architecture. I tried uninstalling 64bit python and installing 32bit version, and then rebuilt boost-python but it didn't work. I need to either tell findboost to lookf for 64bit version files, or somehow create 32bit version files in my boost directory. Is there a possible fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Run cmake from VS command prompt set up for x64 environment

Comment: HOw do i do that?

Comment: Look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206636/force-cmake-to-look-for-x64-bit-libraries-instead-of-x32/52206941#52206941)

Comment: Why do you use Python2? It already has a deprecation countdown.

Comment: The OpenNERO that I am using is very old and uses it, can't help :/

Comment: There is an option in cmake GUI to change the generator, I used it and it worked. Thank s for your help @ixSci :)   https://i.imgur.com/tgl5WAt.png

Comment: @ixSci can you post it as an answer, I will accept it?

Comment: Let's just close it as a duplicate. The answer to this question is the same and they are closely related.